# Can you find the P(A|B,C) if all you have is P(A), P(C), P(B), P(A|C), P(A|B) and P(B) and P(C) are independent?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

Is it possible to find:

$p(A|B,C)$

But all you have is:
$P(A)$
$P(C)$
$P(B)$
$P(A|C)$
$P(A|B)$

and $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ are independent

The farthest i've gotten is

$P(A|B,C) = \frac{P(B,C|A)\times P(A)}{P(B)\times P(C)}$

but $P(B,C|A)$ is not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't find the value of a *three-term* expression (probability expression that includes three events) with only two-term expressions. You'd need additional conditional independence assumptions to reduce the three-term expressions into two-term ones.

Comment: Just to check my logic on this:   
Assuming $P(A,B|C) = P(A|C) \times P(B|C)$  
That means then that:  

$P(A|C) = \frac{P(C|A) \times P(A)}{P(C)} $  

And  

$P(B|C) = \frac{P(C|B) \times P(B)}{P(C)} $   

After substituting and cancelling out terms that means that with that conditional assumption  

$P(C|A,B) = \frac{P(C|A) \times P(B|A)}{P(C)}$

Comment: If you assume $P(A,B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)$, it means $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $C$, which in turn means $P(A|B,C)=P(A|C)$, and you already have it.

Comment: I definitely messed that up and switch A and C around thanks for that clarification.

B and C should be conditionally independent given A:

Assuming $P(B,C|A) = P(C|A) \times P(B|A)$  
That means then that:
$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A|B) \times P(B)}{P(A)} $
And
$P(C|A) = \frac{P(A|C) \times P(C)}{P(A)} $ 
After substituting and cancelling out terms that means that with that conditional assumption
$P(A|B,C) = \frac {P(B|A) \times P(C|A)}{P(A)}$

Comment: Your final formula's numerator needs to be $P(A|B)\times P(A|C)$

Comment: Gah you are correct switched the conditional probabilities back around by accident. Did all that Bayes rule stuff for nothing.... Thanks for all your help on this really appreciated.